# vs 2008 broken snippets functionality

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, code-snippets

Is there a way to reset to the original vb.net snippets that came along with visual studio 2008?

I recently installed a purchased third party lib, that managed to break almost all the default snippets.

I can see that the snippets do physically exist in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VB\Snippets\1033 but only the following sections are loaded to vs 2008:

application
office development
os
wpf

Any help would be appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution !!!

I went to tools > Code snippet Manager
and re-added the C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VB\Snippets\1033 folder

Everything works great now !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reset the IDE-settings by calling it with `/resetsettings`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your SnippetIndex file is broken.  There should be a file at the directory you listed named SnippetIndex.xml.  This is the file that is consulted in order to build the initial list of snippets.  Can you check that file and see how big it is.  It should be at least 500+ lines (mine is 579).

If it's less then this is almost certainly your problem.  You can fix this by repairing the Visual Studio install

1. Go to Control Panel -> Add Remove Programs
2. Select Visual Studio
3. Choose Repair